# redirecting popen output to file in python

Tags: python, pipe, ipc, popen

I have seen lot of answers that `stdout=file` will redirect to a file. But I had a couple of queries.

1. Why doesn't `>file` work.

   ```
   subprocess.Popen([SCRIPT, "R", ">", FILE, "2>", "/dev/null"])
   ```
2. Is this fine

   ```
   with open(FILE,'w+') as f:
       subprocess.Popen([SCRIPT, stdout=f]
       f.close()
   ```

In my case I am trying to run a script in an infinite loop(which does not stop) and there is some other processes monitoring its output.

Does the script keeps writing into it even after f is closed. If yes, how does it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) doesn't allow use `>` to redirect neither output nor error message, from the document:

> `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` specify the executed program’s standard input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively. Valid values are `PIPE`, `DEVNULL`, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing file object, and `None`.
>
> `PIPE` indicates that a new pipe to the child should be created.  `DEVNULL` indicates that the special file `os.devnull` will be used. With the default settings of `None`, no redirection will occur; the child’s file handles will be inherited from the parent.
>
> Additionally, `stderr` can be `STDOUT`, which indicates that the stderr data from the applications should be captured into the same file handle as for `stdout.`

---

And you should use the following code:

```
with open(FILE, 'w+') as f:
    subprocess.Popen([SCRIPT, 'R'],  stdout=f, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL))
```

Because you're using `with`, so no need close the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must try,

```
with open(FILE,'w+') as f:
    subprocess.Popen([SCRIPT, stdout=f, stderr=f])
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to close the file, it should be done automatically