# Python subprocess.Popen.wait(Popen) not redirecting output to file

Tags: python

This is a simple code but it `echo`es the output instead of redirecting output to file:

```py
from subprocess import Popen

Popen.wait(Popen(['echo', 'echo', 'hi', '>', 'test']))
```

This is the output:

```py
echo hi > test
```

But it does not create a file called `test` in the current directory.

I also tried these:

```py
Popen.wait(Popen(['echo', 'echo', 'hi', '> test']))
Popen.wait(Popen(['echo', 'echo', 'hi >', 'test']))
Popen.wait(Popen(['echo', 'hi', '> test']))
Popen.wait(Popen(['echo', 'hi >', 'test']))
Popen.wait(Popen(['echo', 'hi', '> test']))
```

How to do this in this code? I prefer using `Popen.wait(Popen...)`.

Comment: Because you aren't using a shell, so shell redirection won't work! But generally, you should avoid using a shell

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I saw your comment below the answer and tried that and works fine. But why should I avoid using shell?

Comment: Security considerations, but that's if it is untrusted input, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations). If it is trusted input, it isn't bad

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks. I tested my real command in Linux at first, and then I am trying to do it via Python to make it easier and let him do that. The more real command is: `cat big-file > final-file && cat big-file2 >> final-file && sort -n -t . -k 1,1 -k 2,2 -k 3,3 -k 4,4 big-file | tee big-file-sorted` and I think that does not contain security issue. What's your oppinion?

Comment: the issue is whether the input is trusted or not (e.g., the input is formed by user input, the same considerations as you would give to `eval` or to a SQL command to avoid code injection)

Comment: If these are just commands that you are hardcoding it should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) does not allow to use ">" to redirect as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33797447/5351298):

> stdin, stdout and stderr specify the executed program’s standard input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively. Valid values are PIPE, DEVNULL, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing file object, and None.
>
> PIPE indicates that a new pipe to the child should be created. DEVNULL indicates that the special file os.devnull will be used. With the default settings of None, no redirection will occur; the child’s file handles will be inherited from the parent.
>
> Additionally, stderr can be STDOUT, which indicates that the stderr data from the applications should be captured into the same file handle as for stdout.

---

You would need to create the file first, for instance:

```
with open("test", 'w+') as f:
  Popen.wait(Popen(['echo', ' hi'], stdout=f))
```

Comment: To be clear, `subprocess` *can* use this, but it requires a *shell*, so you can do something like `subprocess.Popen("echo hi > test.txt", shell=True)`